# Scheduled Job send_reminder failing with "No such field"

Tags: api, scheduled-reminders, scheduled-job

We're running Civi 4.6.16 and Drupal 7. Our schedule reminders are not sending when the job triggers, or manually through an API call. The backtrace isn't seeming that helpful, to me, but maybe it'll help someone else:

```
Nov 07 11:30:02  [info] $backTrace = #
0 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(897): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
2 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
3 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
4 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-19, 16, (Array:2), "\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
5 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
6 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(929): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'")
7 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
8 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
9 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2445): DB_common->query("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
10 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1637): DB_DataObject->_query("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
11 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(321): DB_DataObject->query("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
12 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1180): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...", TRUE)
13 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(1298): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...", (Array:1))
14 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(1477): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::buildRecipientContacts(4, "20171107113002", (Array:2))
15 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(186): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::processQueue(NULL, (Array:2))
16 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_send_reminder((Array:1))
17 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
18 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("Job", "send_reminder", (Array:1), NULL)
19 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(131): civicrm_api("Job", "send_reminder", (Array:1))
20 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(83): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
21 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(99): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE)
22 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_execute((Array:2))
23 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
24 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("Job", "execute", (Array:2), NULL)
25 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php(111): civicrm_api("Job", "execute", (Array:2))
26 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.php(32): civicrm_cli->callApi()
27 {main}


Nov 07 11:45:02  [info] $backTrace = #0 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(897): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
#4 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-19, 16, (Array:2), "\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
#5 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(929): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'")
#7 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
#9 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2445): DB_common->query("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
#10 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1637): DB_DataObject->_query("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
#11 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(321): DB_DataObject->query("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...")
#12 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1180): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...", TRUE)
#13 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(1298): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\nINSERT INTO civicrm_action_log (reference_date, contact_id, entity_id, enti...", (Array:1))
#14 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(1477): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::buildRecipientContacts(4, "20171107114502", (Array:2))
#15 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(186): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::processQueue(NULL, (Array:2))
#16 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_send_reminder((Array:1))
#17 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#18 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("Job", "send_reminder", (Array:1), NULL)
#19 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(131): civicrm_api("Job", "send_reminder", (Array:1))
#20 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(83): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#21 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(99): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE)
#22 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_execute((Array:2))
#23 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#24 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("Job", "execute", (Array:2), NULL)
#25 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php(111): civicrm_api("Job", "execute", (Array:2))
#26 /www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.php(32): civicrm_cli->callApi()
#27 {main}
```

I appreciate any pointers.

Thanks,
Rachel

Comment: Can you put define('CIVICRM_DEBUG_LOG_QUERY', 1); in your civicrm.settings.php to see the full query where it's failing? As described at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/

Answer (score 1):

I completely forgot to come back to this. The issue turned out to be a scheduled reminder set to go to "membership", but with no membership option selected. The where claus was in fact getting an empty array.